# UserControl with dependency injection Failed to create component

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, user-controls, .net-6.0

I have winform application I am trying to add a UserControl to my form but I get this error
[image]

this is my UserControl

```
private readonly UserService userService;
private readonly UserValidator userValidator;
public UCUsers(UserService userService,UserValidator userValidator)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.userService = userService;
    this.userValidator = userValidator;
}
```

but when I create a constractor without using dependency injection it works fine.
How can I use a UserControl with dependency injection.

Comment: Your design time should not have any dependency to those classes or interfaces.

Comment: Then how can I do it

Comment: Just imagine, what designer code do you expect the Designer generates for your control when it has dependency in constructor?

Comment: I can imagine some possible solutions maybe using a custom serializer and a custom type description provider, but I believe it's not a very good way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Designer needs to generate code for your control; If you have dependencies in constructor, then how the designer can generate a line of code for instantiating your control? What parameters should it pass to the constructor?

```
#region Windows Form Designer generated code
/// <summary>
///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    ...
    this.uCUsers1 = new UCUsers (??????, ??????);
    ...
```

You need to create a parameterless constructor for your UserControl and define some properties for those kind of dependencies. Then at design-time you can use your control, and also at run-time you can set those dependencies, by resolving them through constructor of your form (or directly resolving through the service container).

For example, your user control should be something like this:

```
public class MyUserControl: UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        //...
    }
    public IHelloService HelloServiceInstance{get; set;}
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(HelloServiceInstance!=null)
            MessageBox.Show(HelloServiceInstance.SayHello());
    }
}
```

Then at run-time, for example in `OnLoad` method or `Load` event handler or constructor of your form, just resolve the service and set the HelloServiceInstance property of the user control:

```
public Form1(IHelloService helloService)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myUserControl1.HelloServiceInstance = helloService;
}
```

Comment: It is always a pleasure to learn from you